# how to fix socket error-#11003 in sendmail

Tags: websocket

I'm setting up my smtp mail server for php mail() function, but when
i execute my mail() function code it return `false`.

I tried different ports (in my `sendmail.ini` file) such as 25, 465, 143(imap port), 559, 25025, 587.

`sendmail` error log file shows:

> 18/12/26 19:43:12 : Socket Error # 11003

and debug file shows

> 18/12/26 19:43:12 ** Connecting to 'yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com':25
>     18/12/26 19:43:12 ** Disconnected.
>     18/12/26 19:43:12 ** Disconnected.
>     18/12/26 19:43:12 ** Disconnected.
>     18/12/26 19:43:12 ** Socket Error # 11003

`sendmail.ini`:

```
smtp_server=yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com
smtp_port=25
smtp_ssl=auto
auth_username=yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com
auth_password=....
```

`php.ini` file

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http:
; SMTP=localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
; smtp_port=25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
sendmail_path ="C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -i"
```

my program code

```
$sender = 'yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com';
$recipient = 'yuvrajchoudhary106@gmail.com';
$subject = "php mail test";
$message = "php test message";
$headers = 'From:' . $sender;
if (mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo " Message
 }
 else
 {
    echo "Error: Message not accepted";
 }
```

I expected that I would get the mail but my code says

> Error:Message not accepted

Answer (score 2):

In `sendmail.ini` file change

```
smtp_server=yuvrajchoudhary107@gmail.com
```

to

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
```